# Android Console Public Key

Tags: android, publishing, public-key

OK, I'm confused!

Should I use the public key from "Android Console" when I create keystore for signing apk file?

Does this make sense "If you have developer account, you can sign your application with DEVELOPER KEY. If you haven't acc you can use your OWN key"? What does it mean and what is "developer key".

BTW. I have developer acc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need any specific key, simply create a new keyfile in eclipse by right clicking the project > Export signed application project, then create one

Note: from then on you must always use this key file to sign your app in order to upload and push updates to the play store